# Getting Error MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json

Tags: java, json

I am implementing small application for rest webservice and want to get response in json formate.
But I am getting this error on my `Eclipse` **console**.

Please help me out.

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class book.Test, genericType=class book.Test.
```

[image]

[image]

web.xml File :
[image]

All Jar files :

[image]

I have added all dependencies jar but still i am getting the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: Add jersey-json.jar in your classpath downloaded from below server http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json/1.18

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a dependency: you enabled the `POJOMappingFeature` in the settings so you need to include `jersey-media-moxy` or `jersey-media-json-jackson` in your dependencies. Since your beans have JAXB annotation I guess you'll want both XML and JSON serialization, so MOXy is your choice.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i have created web application in eclipse then how to include dependencies. That is not maven project.

Comment: Download the file, add it to your project dependencies the same way you added the others.